Push Out file out of S3 to external server
how can we push file out of s3 bucket to eternal server using ssh keys on daily basis
on port 10022 at given directory at external server ?
I tried to generate random ssh key pair (public & Private).
Public key is shared to vendor.
Private key is configured to AWS Secreat Manager and trying to use in Lambda to push files.
Expecting a better approach if exist and if not help me the way I am trying to do

You can automate this job by using Amazon EventBridge along with AWS Transfer Family SFTP connectors. For each file that's placed in S3, you'll get an event in eventbridge. You can define a rule in eventbridge for such an event to directly trigger the StartFileTransfer API operation provided by AWS Transfer Family, that uses the SFTP connector to push the file to remote server.
From AWS Transfer Family SFTP connectors - AWS Transfer Family:

AWS Transfer Family SFTP connectors establish a relationship for sending files and messages between Amazon storage and an external partner, using the SFTP protocol. You can send files from Amazon S3 to an external, partner-owned destination. You can also use an SFTP connector to retrieve files from a partner's SFTP server.

You need to store the remote credentials in AWS Secrets Manager.
Use SFTP connectors and tracking their progress - AWS Transfer Family. The benefit is that the service manages the transfer for you.
There is a 40c/GB charge, but Data Transfer does not apply. See: Managed File Transfer Pricing – AWS
